# CRM 2011- Importing data from csv ( N-N relationship between contact and account)

Tags: import, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a situation in Microsoft CRM 2011 in which contacts and accounts are associated N-N. I need to be able to import the data from a cvs file but have not been able to find a solution so far. Any help will be appreciated.

~A

Comment: you should add some details. The question looks very common, undetailed.

Comment: Please support this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32455/microsoft-dynamics-crm?referrer=jHf4j_VcIgLKPEy52a9q2g2) in order to create a community where this question would be in the defined scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the standard import tool in MS CRM 2011. You can only import the data and 1:N relationships.